# what is DebuggerProxy.dll and is this file need for the released isolated shell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx

I have created an isolated shell application base on VS2010 and I found there are two files which I am not familiar with

**DebuggerProxy.dll ,
DebuggerProxy.dll.manifest**

When I output the debug version isolated shell, the two files must be put in the same folder as the shell exe, or there will be side by side error and shell can not be launched at all.

But for the release version isolated shell, if I remove the two files and then the shell can also be launched without error

so what is the file DebuggerProxy.dll used for? Does it need to be put in the same directory with the release version shell application?